# Node.js removing element from associated element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I added a feature where users can pin recipes to their profile. However, when the recipe is deleted, the recipe isn't removed from the user's pinnedRecipes, even though it doesn't appear on the user's show page (the ID stays in the user's pinnedRecipes in the database).

Here's the association between the Recipes and the user's pinnedRecipes:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    admin: {type:Boolean, default: false},
    bio: {type:String, default: "Cet utilisateur n'a pas encore rempli cette section."},
    profileImage: {type:String, default: "http://www.wilwia.com/images/default-user.png"},
    pinnedRecipes:[
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Recipe"
        }
    ]
});

var recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    source: String,
    image: String,
    preplength: String,
    cooklength: String,
    portions: Number,
    description: String,
    ingredients: String,
    instructions: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String,
    },
    comments: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Comment"
            }
        ],
    category: {type:String, enum: ['appetizer', 'salad', 'soup', 'meat', 'pasta', 'breakfast', 'dessert']}
});
```

Here's what I tried, that didn't work (everything works, except removing recipe from pinnedRecipes):

```
    //DESTROY ROUTE
router.delete("/:id", middleware.checkRecipeOwnership, function(req, res){
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundRecipe){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            //delete associated comments
            if(foundRecipe.comments.length > 0){
                Comment.remove({
                _id: {
                    $in: foundRecipe.comments
                }
            }, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
            //delete from every user's pinned recipes
            User.find({pinnedRecipes: "ObjectId(" + foundRecipe._id + ")"}, function(err, foundUsers){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(foundUsers);
                    foundUsers.forEach(function(user){
                        user.pinnedRecipes.remove(foundRecipe);
                        user.save();
                    });
                }
            });
            //remove the campground
            foundRecipe.remove(function(err, recipe){
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
                   res.redirect("/recipes");
               } else {
                   res.redirect("/recipes");
               }
            });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also, here's how recipes are pinned:

```
// PIN ROUTE
router.get("/pin/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundRecipe){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Une erreur s'est produite.");
            res.redirect("/recipes/" + foundRecipe._id);
        } else {
            User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    req.flash("error", "Une erreur s'est produite.");
                    res.redirect("/recipes/" + foundRecipe._id);
                } else { 
                  user.pinnedRecipes.push(foundRecipe);
                  user.save();
                  res.redirect("/recipes/" + foundRecipe._id);
                  req.flash("success", "Pinned recipe"); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

// UNPIN ROUTE
router.delete("/pin/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundRecipe){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Une erreur s'est produite.");
            res.redirect("/recipes/" + foundRecipe._id);
        } else {
            User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    req.flash("error", "Une erreur s'est produite.");
                    res.redirect("/recipes/" + foundRecipe._id);
                } else { 
                  user.pinnedRecipes.remove(foundRecipe);
                  user.save();
                  res.redirect("/recipes/" + foundRecipe._id);
                  req.flash("success", "Pinned recipe"); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your code:

- You are doing 2 asynchronous operations without really waiting for their responses. Always ensure that they all finish. So do one and wait for its callback to execute THEN do the other and wait for its callback to execute THEN do the next and so forth.
- More important: I don't believe `user.pinnedRecipes.remove(foundRecipe)` would remove the reference. You need to [`pull`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)it [scroll to **Removing subdocs** section].

HOWEVER You seem to be trying to do a [cascade delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) but with MongoDB. One way to achieve this is by using [`pre` hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). Take heed to the **Note** in the documentation that it will only be *called when you do `myDoc.remove()`, not when you call `MyModel.remove()`*.

I believe it would simplify your code as such:

```
RecipeSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    var recipe = this;
    // remove recipe comments
    Comment.remove({ _id: { $in: recipe.comments }}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // THEN remove users' recipe references
        User.update({ pinnedRecipes: { $in: [recipe._id] }}, { $pull: recipe._id }, { multi: true }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            next();
        });
    });
});



router.delete("/:id", middleware.checkRecipeOwnership, function (req, res) {
    // notice we didn't do Recipe.remove(req.params.id, cb) 
    // b/c Recipe is the model and that would not trigger the hook
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function (err, recipe) {
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect("back");
        }
        // this will trigger the hook b/c recipe is a document
        recipe.remove(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.redirect("/recipes");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mikey, on the following line (in the hook):         User.update({ pinnedRecipes: { $in: [recipe._id] }, { $pull: recipe._id }, { multi: true }, function (err) {, I get a "Syntax error, unexpected token: {". How do I fix this? Also, shouldn't it be { $in: recipe._id.pinnedRecipes }? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Missing curly bracket `{ pinnedRecipes: { $in: [recipe._id] }}`. I don't think so. You want to find all the users who have `recipe._id` in their array `pinnedRecipes` and then remove it from the array.